# Django slow load and PosgresSQL optimization

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views, django-templates

I have build in app in Django and upload it to Heruko.
I am using SQLPostgres of amazon.

And I have installed the Newrelic plugin and Django Debug Tool.

My problem is slow loading pages all over my app:
I will show you part of my code of a very slow loading page.
can you please point me on what I am doing wrong with my queries ?

*new relic:*

[image]

*Django ToolBug:*

[image]

*Views.py*

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def students(request):
    form = StudentForm()
    form.fields['desc'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['firstname'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['lastname'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['sid'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['studentclass'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['phone'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['main'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    form.fields['submain1'].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
    students = Student.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('students')
    return render(request, "studentform/students.html", {"form": form, "students": students})
```

*templete.html*

```
{% extends 'studentform/controlpanel.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1> תלמידים<a style="float: left; padding-left: 20px" href="{% url 'export_csv'%}"><img style="height: 35px;width: 35px" src="https://d1yjjnpx0p53s8.cloudfront.net/styles/logo-thumbnail/s3/072015/excel_0_0.png?itok=tetyiA_8"></a></h1>
    <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <div class="card-body ">
    <form id="students-form" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
           {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
            </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px" class="row">

            {% endif %}
            <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-12 ">
                <label >{{ field.label }}</label>
                {{ field }}
                </div>

            {% endfor %}

        </div>
          <div style="padding-top: 10px" class="row justify-content-center text-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="צור תלמיד" />
                </div>
    </form>

<hr />

<div class="container">
    <table style="width:100%"  class="display nowrap" id="my_students">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>שם</th>
                <th>שם משפחה</th>
                 <th>ת.ז</th>
                <th>איימיל</th>
                <th>טלפון</th>
                <th>כיתה</th>
                <th>מגמה ראשית</th>
                <th>חוגים</th>
                <th> עדכון</th>
                <th>מחיקה</th>


            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for i in students %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{i.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{i.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{i.sid}}</td>
            <td>{{i.email}}</td>
            <td>{{i.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{i.studentclass.name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.main.name}}</td>
          <td>  {% for n in i.hog.all %}
                {{n.name}}
                {% endfor %}
</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'updatestudent' i.id %}">עדכון</a></td>
           <!-- <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'deletestudent' i.id %}">מחיקה</a></td> -->
            <td><button value="{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deletestu" href="#">מחיקה</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>
</div>
 </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

UPDATE:

I use prefetch_releted and it seems to fix the 230 queries.

but now i have :
335.75 ms (15 queries including 8 similar and 8 duplicates )

ms no change but the number of queries there is change.

[image]

Comment: @Alasdair its payed website.
can you show me how to implement it on my code?

Comment: Have a look at [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), e.g. `students = Student.objects.all().select_related()`.

Comment: @Alasdair it still the same amount of times and same amount of queries it didn't help much.

Comment: Those are the tools you need to decrease the number of queries, I'm afraid I can't go into more detail. I would try adding/remove parts of the view to see what is causing the additional queries, then you can focus on those parts. It will be hard for other people to help when you haven't shown the models.

Answer (score 0):

The problem depends on your database model.
I gues, `speciality` and `subdomain` are set as `foreign keys` to the `student` model.
In that case, if the `student` model needs to be loaded, the load will be aggravated by repeated invocation of models related to the foreign key.
The `select_related()` or `prefetch_related()` option reduces repeated loads because it loads the foreign keys associated with the model at once.

Comment: i used it.
but nothing seems to change: students = Student.objects.all().select_related()

Comment: look at my update. i have used students =  students = Student.objects.all().prefetch_related('submain1','main','hog','studentclass')

Comment: `Select_related()` usually shows better performance than `prefetch_related()` unless the model has `ManyToManyField` relationship.
I recommend you to use `Student.objects.all().select_related('submain1', ....)`.

Comment: you need to write the related fields in select_related(`HERE`).
And the use of `select_related()` in relatively small databases can result in worse performance, even if the amount of Query is reduced. The good performance of `select_related()` is when there are many calls.

Comment: I have many-to-many fields. why the debug say I have duplicate and similar? i have simple view and a simple template page.